# Change background image url

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to change the background of the input button when clicked by using jquery but for the life of me, can't figure out the relative path to make it work.

js file is in root/js folder
css file is in root/css folder

My code looks like this:

```
jQuery($button).css('background',"url(../images/updating_button.gif)");
```

But this just doesn't work...it can't find the image with that path. if I use absolute path it works obviously but i really need it to be relative.

I have tried all combination that I know like:
/images/updating_button.gif
..images/updating_button.gif
images/updating_button.gif
updating_button.gif

Comment: @Rick - What is the absolute path? I'm assuming your `images` folder is also inside `root`... is that correct?

Comment: @Julian - abs path is http://localhost/wp-content/themes/theme/images/updating_button.gif

Comment: @Rick - Oh wow, Wordpress... okay, and what about the file this image is supposed to show up on?

Comment: @Julian - its in localhost/wp-content/themes/theme/

Comment: @Rick - Are there any other relative paths to images you can reference?

Comment: @Julian - in my CSS, the way i reference the button is url(../images/regular_button.gif)

Comment: does it work when you use the absolute path at all? if not, maybe you can start from there - you might have a problem somewhere else not in the image path itself

Comment: sorry, didn't see that in your actual question - of course it works :) now, what is the absolute path to your CSS file? also... if you don't have it yet, I suggest installing Firebug for Firefox and looking at the Console ot Net panel - there you will be able to see where Firefox is trying to pull the image from... and perhaps it can also help you discover the right relative path ;-)

Answer (score 3):

If the URL is static, you could declare a class with the background and maintain your relative path.

In your CSS:

```
.updating { background: url(../images/updating_button.gif); }
```

In your JS:

```
jQuery($button).addClass('updating');
```

Answer (score 1):

You are aware that paths in any inline styles (whether set with JS or not) will be relative to the current HTML document (the URL on the browser's URL bar), not any other file, right?

And why are you avoiding absolute (or domain-relative) URLs?

Comment: Assuming his `images` folder is also inside `root` along with `js` and `css`, his `../images/` should be working--I'm stumped, lol.

Comment: @Matti OK..so what is the solution other than absolute path?

Comment: Rick: Using enough `../` presumably. You forgot to answer my question though. Why no absolute paths? I find page-relative paths very cumbersome, especially with pretty URLs.

Comment: @Matti - because this is a plugin...need to work with anyone without having them edit the code...

Comment: @Rick: Then it might be a better idea to leave styles like that up to a stylesheet. Inline styles ftl anyways

Comment: @Matti - well do you know of a way to do this with CSS cause I dont?

Comment: @Rick: You don't know how to set a background image in CSS?

Answer (score 0):

I wish I could test this for you, but I've had some issues with the url property in the past; adding single quotes inside the `url()` has proved to be the most reliable with relative paths.

`jQuery($button).css('background',"url('../images/updating_button.gif')");`

**Also, what does your file structure look like?**

Comment: @Julian-yeah i tried with single quotes within before but still no go.

Answer (score 0):

The following code might be useful for you:

```
 jquery("button").css("background-image","url(menubar/ajax-loader.gif)");
```

Comment: You should read your own answers. It's almost like chinese to me. A sentence needs at least a subject and a verb.